# Zoomable inner div elements with image

Tags: javascript, html, scrollbar, zooming

I am trying to solve the following issue:

Situation:

I have an outer div with an image included. Additionally it includes multiple inner divs.

Problem:

I want to zoom the image inside the div without zooming/resizing the outer div. Additionally the outer div should provide scrollbars (with overflow: scroll or overflow: auto css option). And the inner divs (element like a square or circle) should hold its position. What I mean is this: Imagine the image is a picture consisting of 16 fields. I put a square into field no. 2/2 (row 2, column 2). When I zoom I don't want to get it lost its position because the image is resizing and the square holds its position.

This is my structure:

#divOuter { position:relative; border: 3px solid red; height:400px;  width:1000px; overflow: auto; font-size: 12px; transform-origin: top left; -o-transform-origin: top left; -moz-transform-origin: top left; -webkit-transform-origin: top left; -ms-transform-origin: top left; z-index:1}

```
<div id="divOuter" >
    <img id="image" width="800" height="400" src="../../Imagefiel.jpg" alt="">
    </img>
    <div id="circleID" title="circle11" style="border: 1px solid black; border-radius:   
    10px; width: 20px; height: 20px; position:absolute;left: 579px; top: 262px; background-
    color: green; z-index:3">
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried two things already:
   - Zoom via transform/scale
     It nearly works as wished but the outer div is resizing too, it shouldn't.
     I used these commands:
 $("#divTest").css('transform', 'scale(' + parseFloat(nScale / 100) + ')');
 $("#divTest").css('font-size', nScale);

- Increase the image size (width/height)
   Problem: The inner divs lost its position, they went outside the fields, they 
            didn't resize/move with the image

I would really appreciate it, if someone could help me with this problem.

Thanks,
sanchez

EDIT: I could solve it :) I included a further div (position: relative) inside the outer div and zoomed it. That way the inner elements got positioned relative to the outer relative div.